# ReactJS: Show/Hide different divs with different IDs using react hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-native, frontend, react-hooks

I have a feature in my project where I have different Icons that will show divs.

Here is my code so far:

```
  const [drawerOpen, setDrawerOpen] = useState(false);
    const [click, setClick] = useState(false);

    const contextData = {
        stateSetters: {
            setDrawerOpen
        }
    };

<Row>
<Col md={8}>
 <Card className="project-card">
   <div>
     <Icon type="down" onClick={() => {
    setClick(!click);
    contextData.stateSetters.setDrawerOpen(!click);
      }}/>
   </div>
  </Card>
 </Col>
<Col md={8}>
 <Card className="project-card">
   <div>
     <Icon type="down" onClick={() => {
    setClick(!click);
    contextData.stateSetters.setDrawerOpen(!click);
      }}/>
   </div>
  </Card>
 </Col>
<Col md={8}>
 <Card className="project-card">
   <div>
     <Icon type="down" onClick={() => {
    setClick(!click);
    contextData.stateSetters.setDrawerOpen(!click);
      }}/>
   </div>
  </Card>
 </Col>
</Row>

<div className={drawerOpen ? 'show-feature-drawer' : 'hide-feature-drawer'}>
   <div className="feature-drawer" id="data-1">

   </div>
</div>
<div className={drawerOpen ? 'show-feature-drawer' : 'hide-feature-drawer'}>
   <div className="feature-drawer" id="data-2">

   </div>
</div>
<div className={drawerOpen ? 'show-feature-drawer' : 'hide-feature-drawer'}>
   <div className="feature-drawer" id="data-3">

   </div>
</div>
```

I am looking for ways on how to open by calling its div id. I tried tweaking the onClick() but it still opens all the divs at once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify the id of the drawer to open instead of the boolean value in state

```
const [drawerOpen, setDrawerOpen] = useState('');
const handleDrawerOpen = (data) => {
    if(data === drawerOpen) {
        setDrawerOpen('');
    } else {
        setDrawerOpen(data);
    }
}
    const contextData = {
        stateSetters: {
            setDrawerOpen: handleDrawerOpen
        }
    };

<Row>
<Col md={8}>
 <Card className="project-card">
   <div>
     <Icon type="down" onClick={() => {
        contextData.stateSetters.setDrawerOpen('data-1');
      }}/>
   </div>
  </Card>
 </Col>
<Col md={8}>
 <Card className="project-card">
   <div>
     <Icon type="down" onClick={() => {
         contextData.stateSetters.setDrawerOpen('data-2');
      }}/>
   </div>
  </Card>
 </Col>
<Col md={8}>
 <Card className="project-card">
   <div>
     <Icon type="down" onClick={() => {
          contextData.stateSetters.setDrawerOpen('data-3');
      }}/>
   </div>
  </Card>
 </Col>
</Row>

<div className={drawerOpen === 'data-1' ? 'show-feature-drawer' : 'hide-feature-drawer'}>
   <div className="feature-drawer" id="data-1">

   </div>
</div>
<div className={drawerOpen === 'data-2' ? 'show-feature-drawer' : 'hide-feature-drawer'}>
   <div className="feature-drawer" id="data-2">

   </div>
</div>
<div className={drawerOpen === 'data-3' ? 'show-feature-drawer' : 'hide-feature-drawer'}>
   <div className="feature-drawer" id="data-3">

   </div>
</div>
```